# How to get the unformatted value of a json response

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, automated-tests, robotframework

When I get the id of the Create User call response and log it on the Create User.

```
 Create a User Call
    ...
    ${response_body}    Convert String To Json    ${response.content}
    Set Test Variable    ${response_body}
    Log    ${response_body}
    @{created_userId}    Get Value From Json    ${response_body}    id
    Set Global Variable    @{created_userId}
    Log    @{created_userId}
```

When I log it, it gets the id that I want to use:

[Logging of Id that I want to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OYQp.png)

```
Test Case 
    ...
    Then Delete Created Spotnana User    @{created_userId}
```

```
Delete a User Call
    [Arguments]    @{created_userId}
    ${response}    Delete Request   uri=test/users/delete/@{created_userId}    headers=${headers}
    ...
```

But when I use it, it returns a formatted variable

```
uri=testendpoint/users/delete/['0745d28c-12b0-463e-abd7-69e19839291e']
```

what I want to use is just this:

```
uri=testendpoint/users/delete/0745d28c-12b0-463e-abd7-69e19839291e
```

I've tried setting it as list and getting it from list

Answer (score 2):

Keyword `Get Value From Json` returns list of values. You must get the first value with `Get From List` keyword.

```
*** Settings ***
Library                     Collections
Library                     JSONLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Jsontest
    ${response}           Set Variable              {"id": "546e0c4d-b810-49e6-a674-0d0f812bb790"}
    ${response_body}=     Convert String To Json    ${response}
    ${created_userId_l}=  Get Value From Json       ${response_body}       id
    Log                   ${created_userId_l}
    ${created_userId}=    Get From List             ${created_userId_l}    0
    Log                   ${created_userId}
```

Comment: this did the trick. thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Simple Python string formatting should do the trick:

```
# assuming you have the json already, you can convert it to string if necessary
json_response = "uri=testendpoint/users/delete/['0745d28c-12b0-463e-abd7-69e19839291e']"

# remove unwanted chars
formatted_uri = json_response.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'",'')

print(formatted_uri)
```

result: `uri=testendpoint/users/delete/0745d28c-12b0-463e-abd7-69e19839291e`